# CADisplayLink displayLinkWithTarget gets immediately released

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ipad, dealloc

I am working with an external lib and for some reason when the test app is designed with storyboards the `CADisplayLink displayLinkWithTarget` method returns an object that is immediately released?

```
    timer = [CADisplayLink displayLinkWithTarget:self selector:@selector(step)];
```

// timer is ZOMBIE

```
    [timer addToRunLoop:[NSRunLoop mainRunLoop] forMode:NSRunLoopCommonModes];
```

Any idea why this happens or how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Please cross check the `timer` data type.

It should be `CADisplayLink` type because  `displayLinkWithTarget` method is returning `CADisplayLink`. Not a `NSTimer` instance.